# Detecting and hiding UIAlertView (or displaying a view over it)

Tags: cocoa-touch

Whenever my app becomes active I show a screen (it's a UIImageView which I add to my subview) and a UIActivityIndicator while I synchronize my data.

However if there was a UIAlertView (and I guess UIActionSheet would also) displaying the moment the user pressed the home button, when he comes back the screen and the UIActivityIndicator show but the alert view is over them.

I see two ways of facing this problem: getting the alertview to hide or showing my screen differently.

Any thoughts on how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do the question only concern UIAlertView produced by your own app or also other alertviews?

Namely do want have to also consider (and find a way to hide) alert views displayed by Push Notifications from other apps, or SMS alerts, etc? If so, this will likely be complicated!

If you only want to consider UIAlertViews of your own applications, don't you need to show the alertview again once the synchronisation of your data has finished? Because if you simply find a way to dismiss the alertview but never show it again, the user will probably miss some information here.

There is no easy/build-in way to do that anyway. Dismissing the alertview will probably generate side-effects, as the alertview could then be considered as validated and the code you have written to handle the buttonClicked event will then probably be triggered whereas in your case it probably isn't meaningful.

But actually hiding the alertview while the data is synching seems a bad idea for me (only my opinion): because if you hide the alertview, the user won't have any other choice than waiting for the data to sync, w/o having anything else to do. Whereas if you let the alertview visible, it will give him a chance at least to be informed of sthg and take time to read the alert while the data is synching.

---

***[EDIT]*** Here is what I tried. This works, but the glow that is below UIAlertViews when onscreen is still visible even after hiding the alertviews.

Note that even if there is a way to hide this glow, I'm not sure doing this will be acceptedwhen submitting your app to the AppStore.

*LCAlertView.h*

```
@interface LCAlertView : UIAlertView
+(void)setAlertViewsVisible:(BOOL)isVisible;
@end
```

*LCAlertView.m*

```
#import "LCAlertView.h"
static UIView* __alertsParentWindow;
static int __alertsCount = 0;

@implementation LCAlertView
+(void)setAlertViewsVisible:(BOOL)isVisible {
    __alertsParentWindow.hidden = !isVisible;
}
-(void)didMoveToWindow {
    if (self.window != nil) {
        // showing
        __alertsParentWindow = [self.window retain];
        ++__alertsCount;
    } else {
        // hiding
        --__alertsCount;
        [__alertsParentWindow release];
        if (__alertsCount==0) __alertsParentWindow = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: I definitely don't wan't to dismiss the alert view. I was thinking simply on setting its hidden property to YES. The thing is, the way I see things, I'd have to save a pointer to every alert, and code a delegate so I reset this pointer once user has dismissed it. Blocking user interaction is not a problem at all here, it's actually the goal

Comment: Ok the problem is (I just tested in a sample project) that `UIAlertViews` are not subviews (or sub-subview etc) of the app's `UIWindow`. So when displayed, an `UIAlertView`'s `superview` is a `_UIAlertOverlayWindow` (Apple's private class), which doesn't have a superview itself... so you can't dig into views displayed in the UIWindow to lookup for all the UIAlertViews, that won't be possible.

Comment: What you can do then is to replace every UIAlertView in your project with a subclass of your own, let's call it `LCAlertView`, and override its `willMoveToWindow` method to be informed when it comes to screen (`window!=nil`) or get dismissed (`window==nil`). Then store the `UIAlertViews` that are still onscreen in an NSArray (e.g. a class variable of your `LCAlertView` subclass) so you can loop thru them

Comment: Edited my answer with one (partial) solution.